# Is there a way to download data from Firebase into csv/excel file using flutter web?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I have a collection of data stored in cloud firestore and Realtime database.

Currently I can view all this data in my flutter web application.

Is there any way I can download all this data as csv/excel file to my computer using flutter web?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Firebase or Firestore to retrieve the data in Excel/CSV format. But since both products have an API, you can certainly write the code to read the data and convert it to such a format.

Edit by Jay

In addition, if you're using the Realtime Database (as indicated in the question), the Firebase Console  does provide and Export option that dumps the data into a flat file, .json type which can directly be opened with excel.

[image]